# Beginner Python list, defining variable

Tags: python-3.x

So I originally completed this task with nothing but a few if, elif statements. But it was requested that I break the work of those statements out into a separate functions as an additional exercise. I need to acquire names to add to a list and have the ability to edit or remove the names. But Im struggling to have the functions return their output to the list.

Here is what I have so far

```
print("Roster Management")


def addplayer():
    name=input("Enter new player name: ")
    roster = [name]
    list(roster)
    roster.append(name)

def removeplayer():
    name = input('Enter player for removal: ')
    roster.remove(name)


def editplayer():
    oldname = input('Enter name you want to edit: ')
    newname = input('Enter new name: ')
    [x.replace(oldname, newname) for x in roster]


while 1==1:
    print('---------- Main Menu ------------')
    print("Choose from the following options")
    print('1. Display Team Roster')
    print('2. Add Member')
    print('3. Remove Member')
    print('4. Edit Member')
    print('9. Exit Program')
    print(" ")
    selection = input("Enter Selection: ")
    if selection == '1':
        for x in roster:
            print(roster)
    elif selection == '2':
        addplayer()
    elif selection == '3':
        removeplayer()
    elif selection == '4':
        editplayer()
    elif selection == '9':
        print("Closing program...")
        break`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're few things that are wrong with your code:

## #1

```
roster = [name] # this creates a new list with a single element in it instead of appending to some existing list
list(roster) # you're trying to convert a list to a list, so not needed
roster.append(name) # you should've some local/global roaster to append to
```

## #2

```
def removeplayer():
    name = input('Enter player for removal: ')
    roster.remove(name) # again, you should've some local/global roaster to append to
    #in case of local you should return the list for further usage, in case of global you can simply remove
```

## #3

```
[x.replace(oldname, newname) for x in roster]
# again you're neither updating any existing list/ nor returned anything
# also check if `x==oldname` then replace with new name
```

## #4

```
for x in roster:
    print(roster) # x is what you should be printing, not the whole list (roaster)
```

So, your updated code with these changes would be something like this:

```
roster = [] 
def addplayer():
    name=input("Enter new player name: ")
    roster.append(name)

def removeplayer():
    name = input('Enter player for removal: ')
    roster.remove(name)


def editplayer():
    global roster
    oldname = input('Enter name you want to edit: ')
    newname = input('Enter new name: ')
    roster = [newname if x == oldname else oldname for x in roster]


print("Roster Management")
while 1==1:
    print('---------- Main Menu ------------')
    print("Choose from the following options")
    print('1. Display Team Roster')
    print('2. Add Member')
    print('3. Remove Member')
    print('4. Edit Member')
    print('9. Exit Program')
    print(" ")
    selection = input("Enter Selection: ")
    if selection == '1':
        for x in roster:
            print(x)
    elif selection == '2':
        addplayer()
    elif selection == '3':
        removeplayer()
    elif selection == '4':
        editplayer()
    elif selection == '9':
        print("Closing program...")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
return list
```

at the end of your definition because right now the definition doesn't know what it is supposed to return. Also in your, if statement you should have

```
print(def())
```

instead of just

```
def()
```

Hope this helps